# eslint / eslint-plugin-react: <form action="Javascript:void(0)" > - no-script-url error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I have a component with a form:

> ***< form action="javascript:void(0)" onSubmit={this.join}>***

Eslint is complaining:

> ***error  Script URL is a form of eval  no-script-url***

Note: I am also using "eslint-plugin-react"

How can I relax this rule or what would be an alternative to the javascript void function?

Comment: You can always disable a rule on a line also using // eslint-disable-line no-script-url

Answer (score 11):

I was having just this problem and then saw this pattern in the official Redux docs and it made a lot of sense to me:

```
<a
  href=""
  onClick={e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    onClick()
  }}
>
  {children}
</a>
```

[Source](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react)

That's what I'll be doing from now on.

Comment: if used as one string need ';'  <a href="" onClick={e => {e.preventDefault(); onClick() }}>{children}</a>

Comment: Blank href gives warning : The href attribute requires a valid value to be accessible. Provide a valid, navigable address as the href value. If you cannot provide a valid href, but still need the element to resemble a link, use a button and change it with appropriate styles. Learn more: https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/HEAD/docs/rules/anchor-is-valid.md

Answer (score 7):

**I disabled it:**

```
"no-script-url": 0
```

Comment: hi can you please share configuration,  where did you put  this line. I have tried in .eslintrc and also in eslintrc.json not working. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Actually it is wrong to disabled it, because `javascript:` is like eval for browser, and eval is evil as people know.

Alternatively, you don't need to put `action` prop. `preventDefault` in your `join` method instead.
For example;

```
function join(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`e.preventDefault()` change with `javascript:void(0)`

```js
<form action={
    e => {
        e.preventDefault()
    }
} onSubmit={this.join}>
 //...   
</form>
```

Or add rule in `package.json` file

```js
"eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ],
    "rules": {
       //...
      "no-script-url": "off",
       //...
    }
  },
```